# How to package ruby on rails app into an executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, executable

I created an app using ruby on rails and would like to share it with someone. How can I create an executable so they can simply download and run the app?

I searched many answers online but they seem to be outdated and dont work for the current ruby version.

I have am using ruby 3.2.3 and rails 7.1.3

Comment: Which tools have you tried to generate an executable? Also, for which OS?

Comment: I would configure a Docker container with the application and all its dependencies and share that one. Bonus points for being able to use such a container for other purposes too, like easier development setup, CI builds or deployment to production.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails is a web development framework, so it is not intended to be compiled into executable files that can be sent via an archive. If you intend to show how an application created in Ruby on Rails works to someone else, you should consider mounting it on a web server with tools like [Kamal](https://kamal-deploy.org/) to simplify the process.

You can mount the application in a Docker container that installs all the necessary dependencies and a script that simply builds the container and runs it.

On the other hand, you can use [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) to mount your application locally and set up a network environment that will allow others to access it via a link. However, remember that the application will be running on your computer. The other person accesses it in the same way they access a social network (through a request to a server).

As for the Ruby language, it is not compiled either but is interpreted at runtime, translating it into bytecodes that are executed by the hardware. There are ways to compile Ruby like [OCRA](https://github.com/larsch/ocra) and [Ruby Packer](https://github.com/pmq20/ruby-packer). Rails has nothing to do with it here, this is just for Ruby. These libraries are not prepared for serious projects, anyway.

Instead, languages ​​like Rust and C compile and generate an executable file that has no dependencies. That is, the hardware can read directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are open source alternatives, like [Ruby Packer](https://github.com/pmq20/ruby-packer) and [Traveling Ruby](https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby) which may be among the ones you already looked at. Neither has been updated in a while, so they may or may not be able to do what you need.

Then while researching this question for myself too, I found a commercial solution named **RubyEncoder**. It seems to support Ruby up to version 3.2. You can look for it with a search engine. It seems promising, and is updated, but costs money.

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/pmq20/ruby-packer/issues/179) for two new open source projects that seem to be currently maintained:

> https://github.com/tamatebako/tebako
> provides Ubuntu, Alpine and MacOS packaging
>
> https://github.com/tamatebako/aibika
> provides Windows packaging

Comment: he asked for ruby on rails, those gems also support RoR? or just Ruby?

Comment: @BrunoCostanzo The RubyEncoder manual is available online and it has a chapter devoted to encoding Rails apps. So we know that one should work. All the other projects talk about Rails, or have Rails mentioned in the issue tracker. Some people with success, others without. Your mileage may vary, but it means we can consider all of them potential candidates for Rails too.